# How to draw this genogram using LaTeX/TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm a medical student and I need to write a report on a patient for next week. I'm fairly new to LaTeX, so I was wondering if there is a way of creating a genogram like the one below. It needs to have both the usual family tree and the type/quality of the relationships between each person.

Is there a package that could make this easier? I have zero experience with TikZ and graphics, and I feel I won't have time to do this.

I found an earlier question regarding genograms, but they were much simpler, and it was already 1 year old.

[image]

Comment: I guess it can be done using TikZ (not that I can do it) but why not just include the picture you have provided?

Comment: For next week? Hum... too complicated to do this with `tikz` in so short time.

Comment: the image is from a friend's report, using word. to do it with an external program is also a possibility, I am looking for an "in-house" solution for styling sake. I guess the most important thing is the actual genogram, the "relationships" lines can be drawn in a different graphic.

Comment: There's [an example of a family tree](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/family-tree/) at _texample.net_

Comment: I'd probably do it in Inkscape and export it to TikZ

Comment: An up vote does not suffice; complicated diagrams like this are far more trouble than they're worth if you hand-code them. It just doesn't fit the bill. Use Inkscape and export, or use another vector image editor and export to PDF and include it from there.

Comment: This reminds me of [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141262/28346). The `matrix` library from `tikz` seems to ease things up. Besides this, I'm surprised that medical students also use Latex. I thought its users are rather from math/physics.

Comment: @Jost I use it too and I am a languages student. :P

Answer (score 8):

I tried to do this in `tikz`, the code is quite long but well...

I managed to do everything **except those irregular sine paths**. I'm afraid I'm not at that level yet. If I find I solution I'll let you know but I'm not sure.

Please note that there might be better solutions than this one, and if you need to do this multiple times, it would be better for you to look for ways to automatize a lot of the options in some way.

[image: graph]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, decorations, decorations.pathmorphing, shapes.arrows, snakes}

\definecolor{outerblue}{RGB}{50,100,170}
\definecolor{innerblue}{RGB}{70,110,170}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{155,210,220}

\tikzset{sqr/.style={draw=outerblue, thick,rectangle,fill=white,minimum size=1cm},
        cir/.style={draw=outerblue, thick,circle,fill=white,minimum size=1cm},
        every label/.style={font=\tiny, text width=2cm},
        liltext/.style={font=\tiny, inner sep=.5mm},
        bigarrow/.style={single arrow,
                        single arrow head extend=.2mm,
                        draw=outerblue,
                        fill=innerblue,
                        line width=1pt,
                        shorten >= 4.5pt,
                        minimum size=4mm, 
                        text width=4mm,
                        inner sep=.1mm},
        doublea/.style={thick, fill=none, double, double distance=1.5pt},
}

\newcommand{\dil}[1]{\draw[very thick] ($(#1.south west)+(-2mm, -2mm)$) -- ($(#1.north east)+(2mm, 2mm)$);}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    % SHAPES

    \node (sqr1) [sqr, label={[align=right,anchor=south east]left:Daniel\\\color{red}?\\"foi-se abaixo depois da morte da minhã mãe"}]  {}; \dil{sqr1}
    \node (sqr2) [sqr, right=8mm of sqr1, label={[anchor=south west]right:João\\\color{red}?\\Pneumonia}] {}; \dil{sqr2}
    \node (cir1) [cir, right=1.5cm of sqr2, label={[anchor=south west]right:Maria José\\\color{red}62\\"coração"}] {}; \dil{cir1}
    \node (sqr3) [sqr, right=2cm of cir1, label={[anchor=south west]right:Jorge\\\color{red}?\\AVG}] {}; \dil{sqr3}
    \node (cir2) [cir, right=1cm of sqr3, label={[anchor=south west]right:Teresa\\\color{red}?\\"causa natural"}] {}; \dil{cir2}

    \node (cir3) [cir, below=1.5cm of sqr1, xshift=5mm, label={[align=right, anchor=south east]left:Fernanda\\65\\AVC (2011)}] {};
    \node (sqr4) [sqr, right=2.3cm of cir3, label={[align=right, anchor=south east]left:António\\75\\HTA, DM, asma, HBP}] {};
    \node (sqr5) [sqr, right=1cm of sqr4, yshift=8mm, label={[yshift=4mm,align=right, anchor=south east]left:?}] {};  \dil{sqr5}
    \node (cir4) [cir, below=1.5cm of sqr3, xshift=1cm, label={[anchor=south west]right:Gilda\\71\\Dislipidémia AVC (2005)}] {};

    \node (sqr6) [sqr, below=1.5cm of cir3, label={[align=right,anchor=south east]left:Armando\\?}] {};
    \node (cir5) [cir, below=1.5cm of sqr4, xshift=-5mm, label={[anchor=south west]right:Cristina\\45}] {};
    \node (sqr7) [sqr, right=2.5cm of cir5, label={[yshift=4mm,align=right,anchor=south east]left:?}] {};
    \node (cir6) [cir, below=1.5cm of cir4, xshift=5mm, label={[anchor=south west]right:Angela\\43}] {};

    \node (sqr8) [sqr, below=1.5cm of sqr6, xshift=-2mm, label={[align=right,anchor=south east]left:Igor\\16}] {};
    \node (sqr9) [sqr, below=1.5cm of cir5, xshift=2mm, label={[anchor=south west]right:Leandro\\12}] {};
    \node (sqr10)[sqr, below=1.5cm of sqr7, xshift=1cm, label={[anchor=south west]right:Bruno Rafaeli\\20}] {};

    % LINES

    \draw[doublea, draw=lightblue] (sqr1.south) -- (sqr4.north); 
    \draw[doublea, draw=lightblue] (sqr2.south) -- (sqr4.north); 
    \draw[doublea, draw=lightblue] (cir1.south) -- (sqr4.north); 
    \draw[doublea, draw=lightblue] (sqr4.east) -- (cir4.west);
    \draw[doublea, draw=lightblue] (sqr4.south) -- (cir5.north);
    \draw[thick, draw=lightblue] (cir4.south) -- (cir6.north);

    \draw (sqr1) |- ([xshift=0em,yshift=-5mm]sqr1.south) -| (cir1.south);
    \draw (sqr2) |- ([xshift=0em,yshift=-3mm]sqr2.south) -| (cir1.south);
    %\draw (sqr3.south) |- to node[near start,above](center1){H} -| (cir2.south); 
    \draw (sqr3) |- ([xshift=0em,yshift=-4mm]sqr3.south) -| (cir2.south);
    \draw (cir4) -- ($(sqr3.south)!0.5!(cir2.south)+(0mm,-4mm)$);  
    \draw (cir3) |- ([xshift=0em,yshift=4mm]cir3.north) -| (sqr4.north);
    \draw[decoration={snake}, decorate] ($(cir3.north)!0.5!(sqr4.north)+(0mm,4mm)$) -- ($(sqr2.south)!0.5!(cir1.south)+(0mm,-3mm)$);
    \draw (sqr5) |- ([xshift=0em,yshift=-1cm]sqr5.south) -| (cir4.south);

    \draw (sqr4) |- ([xshift=0em,yshift=-6mm]sqr4.south) -| (cir4.south);   
    \draw ($(sqr4.south)!0.5!(cir4.south)+(0mm,-6mm)$) node[liltext, above]{1966} -- ($(cir5.north)!0.5!(cir6.north)+(0mm,6mm)$); 
    \draw (cir5) |- ([xshift=0em,yshift=6mm]cir5.north) -| (cir6.north);

    \draw (sqr6) |- ([xshift=0em,yshift=-3mm]sqr6.south) -| (cir5.south);
    \draw ($(sqr6.south)!0.5!(cir5.south)+(0mm,-3mm)$) node[liltext, above]{1995} -- ($(sqr8.north)!0.5!(sqr9.north)+(0mm,3mm)$); 
    \draw (sqr8) |- ([xshift=0em,yshift=3mm]sqr8.north) -| (sqr9.north);

    \draw (sqr7) |- ([xshift=0em,yshift=-3mm]sqr7.south) -| (cir6.south);
    \draw (sqr10) -- ($(sqr7.south)!0.5!(cir6.south)+(0mm,-3mm)$) node[liltext, above, anchor=south east]{1999};
    \draw[doublea] ($(sqr7.south)!0.5!(cir6.south)+(-2mm,-5mm)$) -- ($(sqr7.south)!0.5!(cir6.south)+(2mm,-1mm)$);

    \node[bigarrow, anchor=east, rotate=225] at ($(sqr4.north east)+(.5mm,.5mm)$) {};

    \draw [red!60!black, dashed, thick] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {
    ([yshift=2mm]sqr4.north east) 
    ([yshift=-3mm]sqr5.south west) 
    ([yshift=-3mm]sqr5.south east) 
    ([yshift=2mm]cir4.north west) 
    ([yshift=1.7mm]cir4.north east) 
    ([xshift=1.2mm]cir4.east) 
    ([yshift=-3mm]cir4.south) 
    ([xshift=-1.8mm,yshift=-2.3mm]sqr4.south)
    %([xshift=-1mm]sqr4.west)
    ([yshift=1mm]sqr4.north west)
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```